# How to get UTF-8 Hashtags without special chars in PHP

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, hashtag

I've got an issue extracting only UTF-8 letters like `ä,ö,ü,ß` (let's say letters that are used in words) without chars like `!"§$%&/()+'` etc.

```
  function getHashtags($string)
{
    $string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
    preg_match_all('/(\#)([^\s]+)/u', $string, $matches);
    if ($matches) {
        $hashtagsArray = array_count_values($matches[0]);
        $hashtags = array_keys($hashtagsArray);
        $hashtagLine = '';
        foreach ($hashtags as $hashs) {
            $hashs = strtolower(trim($hashs));
            $hashtagLine .= $hashs;
        }
    }
    return $hashtagLine;
}
```

that is my current solution, it receives a string text and extracts the hashtags out of it and returns them in line. The Problem is that with this solution also hashtags being processed like `#example!"$/%` (and not being cut just before the `!` like `#example`).

Does someone has an (Regex) approach to extract twitter like UTF-8 hashtags clean, without those unwanted punctuation characters, from a string in PHP?

Comment: What about `"/(?<=^|\\P{L})#\\b\\p{L}+\\b/u"`? https://regex101.com/r/qP5oI9/3

Comment: So, what characters exactly *are* allowed and which are *disallowed*? "Special chars" isn't a thing. Do you mean *letters vs. punctuation*? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use unicode property:

```
preg_match_all('/#(\p{L}+)/u', $string, $matches);
```

`\p{L}` stands for any letter in any language.

Comment: If you follow Twitter convention, a hashtag can include underscore and not start with a number. `/(?<=^|\P{L})(#\b\p{L}[\p{L}\d_]+)/u` seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below regex

```php
$regex = "(?:#)([\p{L}\p{N}_](?:(?:[\p{L}\p{N}_]|(?:\.(?!\.))){0,28}(?:[\p{L}\p{N}_]))?)";
```

it works similar to Facebook and Instagram hashtags.

gist in github: https://gist.github.com/khanzadimahdi/2ecfe1ba38860db132b4543ab5126926

and test it using below links:

https://regexr.com/4suqt

https://regex101.com/r/4SAxik/1

https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=113956